# JS/jQuery - Replace and return string with dynamic number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

```
<p>
    <div></div>
    ", 3 apples"
</p>

<p>
    <div></div>
    ", 0 apples"
</p>

<p>
    <div></div>
    ", 1 apple"
</p>
```

How do I use jQuery to search for strings starting with `, digit` and then replace it with `<span></span> digit` ?

So `", 1 apple"` will be `<span></span>"1 apple"`

And `", 0 apples"` will be `<span></span>"0 apples"`

So far my code is:

```
$(this).html($(this).html().replace(/ \|\d/, '<span></span>' + d)
```

But `d` is not defined of course.

Comment: Use a regular expression replacement.

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added what I have tried but stuck at this

Comment: Capture digit into captruing group and them use it in replacement pattern.

Comment: Use `.replace(/("?),\s*(\W*\d+)/g, '$1<span></span>$2')` or ``.replace(/,\s*(\d+)/g, '<span></span>$1')`` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/lZj1Eo/2)).

Comment: Thanks, I studied the examples and I'm able to get this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
.replace(/",\s*(?=\d)/g, '<span></span>"')
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/OlZWuo/1).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ",                       '",'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Code example:

```js
const string = `", 1 apple"
", 0 apples"`;
console.log(string.replace(/",\s*(?=\d)/g, '<span></span>"'));
```